# Instantiate one class variable with another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a the following classes

```
namespace MyClass.Models
{
    public class Address : IIdentity
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
        public string user_id { get; set; }
        public int building_number { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
        public string area { get; set; }
        public string county { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public bool iscustomer { get; set; }
        public bool islive { get; set; }
        public string customer_id { get; set; }
        public string store_id { get; set; }
        public string phone_id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace MyClass.Models
{
    public class User : IIdentity
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public bool isrestricted { get; set; }
        public bool isbanned { get; set; }
        public DateTime renewaldate { get; set; }
        public string address_id { get; set; }
        public string userlevel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is create some test data to propagate through to my database so I can test my MVC5 website.

I am attempting to perform a look up on my instance of User within the Address class like so

```
user_id = context.User.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.address_id == id)
```

where id points to the id within the class I and trying instantiate.

VS2013 is saying that id does not exist in the current context which makes sense. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to achieve or am I better off setting the my _id from within the class itself and will that be okay when I run update-database from within the package manager console?

For example, the address class would become

```
namespace MyClass.Models
{
    public class Address : IIdentity
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
        public string user_id { get {user_id = Users.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.address_id == id).id; } }
        public int building_number { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
        public string area { get; set; }
        public string county { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public bool iscustomer { get; set; }
        public bool islive { get; set; }
        public string customer_id { get {customer_id = Customers...;} }
        public string store_id { get {store_id = Stores...;} }
        public string phone_id { get {phone_id = Phones...;} }
    }
}
```

Comment: `user_id = Users.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.address_id == id).id;` should be `return Users.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.address_id == id).id;`. You can also try calling id using the `this` keyword. `this.id`

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Your Address class has an `id` field so why does it make sense that VS says it doesn't exist? What is the context in which you are calling that code? Also I'm confused as to what you are trying to do in your final example. do you mean `return` instead of `user_id =` since your user_id which you are getting has no setter and the getter doesn't return anything...

Comment: @JLevett - I tried the this method, but that wasn't allowing me to access the id from within the address class.

Comment: @Chris - I don't know why VS2013 would get confused either, sorry, yes, meant return (had to dash to get a phone call while typing)